# How to convert dynamic SQL query to static query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have below dynamic script in SQL Server

```
DECLARE @ArchiveDbName NVARCHAR(100)
SELECT TOP 1 @ArchiveDbName = ls.ArchiveDbName
FROM   LocalSetting ls

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) =
        'SELECT BusinessDocTypeID,
       RegDate,
       PersonID,
       ProductCode,
       bddv.Group4Code,
       NominalCode,
       UnitID,
       UnitName,
       ProductDescription,
       GrossWeight,
       NetWeight,
       Qty,
       SalePrice,
       UnitPrice,
       TotalNetWeight,
       TotalGrossWeight,
       TotalPrice,
       w.WHCode,
       @FinancialYear
FROM   ' + @ArchiveDbName +
        '.dbo.udfv_BusinessDocDetailView(@RunDate) AS bddv
       INNER JOIN dbo.udft_BusinessDoc(@RunDate) bd
            ON  bd.BusinessDocNo = bddv.BusinessDocNo
       INNER JOIN dbo.udft_WHDoc(@RunDate) w
            ON  w.WHDocNo = bd.WHDocNo
       WHERE  (bd.BusinessDocTypeID = @BusinessDocTypeID)
              AND bd.RegDate BETWEEN @FromShamsiDate AND @ToShamsiDate'
```

I'd like to get static form of that. is there any method to get this conversion?

Actually I want to use dynamic query in table valued function. But SQL Server doesn't let me that choice.

Comment: You cannot convert this to a "static" query, since the table name is being passed in as a parameter. Doing so **requires** the use of dynamic SQL - and there's no workaround or other solution, either (other than **not** passing in the table name as a parameteR)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to use above dynamic query at the end part of my Table Valued Function. but it seems using dynamic query in that function is impossible.

Comment: is there any flexible solution to access another database in same instance without writing or knowing its name? I don't want to use database name manually. (I don't want to use synonyms. because in synonyms we should use database name manually again.)

Comment: I don't think so. **Either** you really need to be able to parametrize the table name --> then you **must use** dynamic SQL and therefore **cannot** put this into a table-valued function. **OR** you want to use a table-valued function by all means, then in that case you **cannot** parametrize the table name, it must be specific explicitly

Comment: OK, so you suggest me to use stored procedure instead of table valued function? is it optimized way to select from procedure instead of table valued function in upper procedures that uses it?

Comment: I am saying if you **must keep** the parametrized table name, then yes, you **must use** something else other than a function - since functions don't support dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using a SQL only solution.  It will have to be dynamic. One alternative solution would be to construct the query in .NET and execute then execute it via ADO.net. It would really be the same as dynamic SQL (but technically not)

Comment: according to my application, above query should be executed at SQL server side.